# meaning of these symbols of distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

I am looking for an explanation of what the following "symbols" mean.

1. $h \sim CN (0, \lambda )$  ?

Complex normal distribution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JwXS.png)

2. $h \sim N_{C} (0, \lambda )$  ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqgcM.png)

Comment: The first example is used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution#Complex_standard_normal_random_variable) with the meaning you've suggested, but a text should hopefully always make its meaning clear, so I recommend reading the second carefully to see whether it ever defines $\mathcal{N}_{\Bbb C}$.